# How to enable protected extensions

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I wanna activate a protected extension, in this case "System - Language Filter" extension. I know that normally this extensions is avaiable to enable, but in my case, it doesn't work, because the extension status shows "protected extension". 
Someone knows the solution?

Best regards,
Marco Barbosa

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", what do you mean? The plugin appears enabled but isn't doing it's job? It keeps reverting back to "disabled"? Are any errors, warnings or notice messages being shown when trying to enable it? Have you ensured you're running the latest version of Joomla (3.3.3)?

Comment: @Lodder i already edit the post. I just can't activate, because the status shows "protected extension".

Comment: Please firstly ensure you are running Joomla 3.3.3 which is the latest version. Have you changed any core Joomla files? I only ask as this is not normal behavior. I have just tried to enable the same plugin as you and it worked fine for me. The only time I would expect a similar error is if I try to uninstall a protected extension which you are not doing (hopefully).

Comment: @Lodder, Yes, i am running the 3.3.3 version. Ofc that i'm not trying to unninstal. I'm just trying to install, and joomla gives me an error saying "Edit state is not permitted" beucase it's a protected extension here. It's pretty strange

Comment: Now you are saying you're trying to install? Which is it, installing or enabling an extension? As asked before, have you modified any core Joomla files?

Comment: @Lodder, my mistake, i meant "enable" instead "install". No, didn't modified anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please open `System -> Global Check-in`, select all check boxes and press `Check In`.

Then go to `Extensions -> Plugin Manager` and press on the status button to get the plugin enabled.

Answer (score 2):

I had the lock and the "protected extension" message on my System - Language manager plugin. Then I saw that I was in the Extension Manage area. One has to go to the Plugin manager (extensions->plugins) and use that menu. There it is not locked. I searched the whole web for this ;-)